# Mule application deploy issue

Tags: mule, pom.xml, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

I am new on Mule and Anypoint Studio and want to deploy a project. When I run it I get exceptions that might get caused by a jar dependency called wrapper for Mapping the java classes that says could not be found, how do I have to install this dependency? And if it is not the dependency then how to fix it? I don't know what to do at this point so I appreciate any answer.

I get the following exceptions when I try to run and compile the project:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [net.inspira.api.transformers.json.ObjectToJsonMapper] for bean with name 'JsonMapper' defined in class path resource [spring/config-beans.xml]; nested exception is org.mule.runtime.module.artifact.api.classloader.exception.CompositeClassNotFoundException: Cannot load class 'net.inspira.api.transformers.json.ObjectToJsonMapper': [
    Class 'net.inspira.api.transformers.json.ObjectToJsonMapper' has no package mapping for region 'domain/default/app/mambo-supply'., 
    Cannot load class 'net.inspira.api.transformers.json.ObjectToJsonMapper': [
    Class 'net.inspira.api.transformers.json.ObjectToJsonMapper' has no package mapping for region '/domain/default'., 
    Class 'net.inspira.api.transformers.json.ObjectToJsonMapper' not found in classloader for artifact 'container'.]]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:641) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1490) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1013) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:741) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.mule.extension.spring.api.SpringConfig.lambda$configure$0(SpringConfig.java:63) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:265) ~[mule-core-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:1032) ~[mule-core-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:970) ~[mule-core-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.extension.spring.api.SpringConfig.configure(SpringConfig.java:58) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.MuleArtifactContext.prepareObjectProviders(MuleArtifactContext.java:311) ~[mule-module-spring-config-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.MuleArtifactContext.prepareBeanFactory(MuleArtifactContext.java:303) ~[mule-module-spring-config-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:556) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:102) ~[mule-module-spring-config-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:94) ~[mule-core-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:111) ~[mule-core-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:73) ~[mule-core-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:69) ~[mule-core-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:132) ~[mule-core-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:61) ~[mule-core-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.context.DefaultMuleContext.initialise(DefaultMuleContext.java:352) ~[mule-core-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:177) ~[mule-core-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:60) ~[mule-core-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.artifact.ArtifactContextBuilder.lambda$build$1(ArtifactContextBuilder.java:485) ~[mule-module-deployment-model-impl-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:224) ~[mule-core-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:1075) ~[mule-core-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:993) ~[mule-core-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.artifact.ArtifactContextBuilder.build(ArtifactContextBuilder.java:397) ~[mule-module-deployment-model-impl-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.application.DefaultMuleApplication.doInit(DefaultMuleApplication.java:237) ~[mule-module-deployment-model-impl-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:206) ~[mule-module-deployment-model-impl-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:265) ~[mule-core-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:1032) ~[mule-core-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:970) ~[mule-core-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.artifact.DeployableArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(DeployableArtifactWrapper.java:146) ~[mule-module-deployment-model-impl-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.artifact.DeployableArtifactWrapper.init(DeployableArtifactWrapper.java:89) ~[mule-module-deployment-model-impl-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArtifactDeployer.doInit(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:133) ~[mule-module-deployment-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:60) ~[mule-module-deployment-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:481) [mule-module-deployment-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:470) [mule-module-deployment-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer.internalDeployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:578) [mule-module-deployment-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployOrRedeployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:543) [mule-module-deployment-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:387) [mule-module-deployment-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:53) [mule-module-deployment-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:240) [mule-module-deployment-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.run(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:311) [mule-module-deployment-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:151) [mule-module-deployment-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:156) [mule-module-deployment-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:256) [mule-module-launcher-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.reboot.internal.MuleContainerWrapper.start(MuleContainerWrapper.java:53) [mule-module-boot-ee-4.4.0-20220824.jar:4.4.0-20220824]
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$11.run(WrapperManager.java:4537) [wrapper-3.5.50.jar:3.5.50]
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.module.artifact.api.classloader.exception.CompositeClassNotFoundException: Cannot load class 'net.inspira.api.transformers.json.ObjectToJsonMapper': [
    Class 'net.inspira.api.transformers.json.ObjectToJsonMapper' has no package mapping for region 'domain/default/app/mambo-supply'., 
    Cannot load class 'net.inspira.api.transformers.json.ObjectToJsonMapper': [
    Class 'net.inspira.api.transformers.json.ObjectToJsonMapper' has no package mapping for region '/domain/default'., 
    Class 'net.inspira.api.transformers.json.ObjectToJsonMapper' not found in classloader for artifact 'container'.]]
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.module.artifact.api.classloader.exception.ClassNotFoundInRegionException: Class 'net.inspira.api.transformers.json.ObjectToJsonMapper' has no package mapping for region 'domain/default/app/mambo-supply'.
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.grupoareas</groupId>
    <artifactId>mambo-supply-2017</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-M4</version>
    <packaging>mule-application</packaging>
    <name>mambo-supply</name>
    <description>Application migrated with MMA</description>
    <properties>
        <mule.tools.version>1.1</mule.tools.version>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <mule.version>3.8.4</mule.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <munit.version>2.2.5</munit.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloveretl</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloveretl-engine</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.inspira.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-transformers</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-secure-configuration-property-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-java-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-compatibility-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-db-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-scripting-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-json-module</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-spring-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.17.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.17.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.17.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.17.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-objectstore-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-apikit-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>anypoint-exchange</id>
            <name>Anypoint Exchange</name>
            <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>mulesoft-release</id>
            <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/munit</directory>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-clover-plugins</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.cloveretl</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>cloveretl-engine</artifactId>
                                    <version>3.8.4</version>
                                    <type>zip</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <unzip dest="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}" src="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/cloveretl-engine.zip"/>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>munit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <coverage>
                        <runCoverage>true</runCoverage>
                        <formats>
                            <format>html</format>
                        </formats>
                    </coverage>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <sharedLibraries>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                    </sharedLibraries>
                    <classifier>mule-application</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <args>-parameters</args>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: How is the library used or referenced in the application? That would be helpful to know.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is related to the class `net.inspira.api.transformers.json.ObjectToJsonMapper`. This class seems to be coming from artifact `net.inspira.api:api-transformers:2.0.0`. Since a quick search in Maven Central founds nothing related to that, I'll assume it is a proprietary library that your company uses. You would need to ask inside where it comes and how to install it.

Having said that, if there was no Maven error at built time, the dependency has been accessible to the build and the issue may be that the application can not see it because of Mule 4 classloader isolation. Try adding a [Shared Library](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/mmp-concept#configure-shared-libraries) entry to the pom to make it visible. Example:

```
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>net.inspira.api</groupId>
                            <artifactId>api-transformers</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
```

Put it with the other similar entries.

As a side note, this application seems to have been migrated from Mule 3 using the Mule Migration Assistant tool. Such migrations are not fully automated and required developers familiar with Mule 3 and Mule 4 to complete them. If you are new to Mule and the migration is not complete it may be extra hard for you to make it work.

Comment: Thank you it solved that issue but now I get an exception "org.mule.runtime.deployment.model.api.DeploymentInitException:    PropertyBatchUpdateException: Failed properties: Property 'mimeType' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MediaType cannot be parsed: null" what is this and how can I make it not null?

Comment: You have to open a separate question for the new issue.